# QHow do I use QRegExp to filter findChildren()

Tags: python, pyside

I have a grid with a load of QFrame objects in it, let's call them "box_#".

I'm using findChildren for some behavior,

I want to add other QFrame objects to the layout.

findChildren has a QRegExp in the signature, how do I use it to filter my QFrame objects? not very faimiliar with regExp..

like so:

```
self.grid.parentWidget().findChildren(QtWidgets.QFrame, "box_*").
```

i.e. how do I get only the QFrame objects with objectName "box_1","box_2" and so on...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use `^`:

```
self.grid.parentWidget().findChildren(QtGui.QFrame, QtCore.QRegExp("^box_"))
```

Comment: @SEJM If my answer helps you, do not forget to mark it as correct, if you do not know how to do it, review the [tour], that's the best way to thank :)